# How to test BehaviourSubject next function?

Tags: angular, jasmine, rxjs, behaviorsubject

I am trying to test a service that is using a `BehaviourSubject`, however I am not exactly sure how. Here is my service:

```
export class ProductService {
  private changes$: BehaviorSubject<User[]> = new BehaviorSubject([]);

  get products() { return this.changes$.asObservable() as Observable<any>; }

  getProducts() {
    this.http.get(...)
      .subscribe((products) => {
        this.changes$.next(products);
    }
  }

  filterById(id: number) {
    let products = this.products$.getValue().filter(...);
    // Maybe I will have some more filter logic here. 
    // I want to test that the filter logic is returning the correct product
    this.changes$.next(products);
  }
...
}
```

Here is my test. I want to be able to test the filter logic of my service. But since I am mocking the data, `this.product$.getValue()` will be empty and the filter will not run.

```
it('should filter the products and return the correct product)',
    inject([ProductService], (service: ProductService) => {
      const usersSpy = spyOnProperty(service, 'products', 'get').and.returnValue(Observable.of(mockGetResponse));
      service.products.subscribe((res) => {
        // How do I continue here?  
        // the `this.products$.getValue()` 
        // will not contain any items, 
        // because I am mocking the data. 
        service.findByUserId(1); 
      });
    }));
```

Comment: May I suggest not using a `BehaviorSubject` in this case? It seems unnecessary. That will then simplify your test.

Answer (score 8):

When you're testing an observable sequence, it's important to keep in mind that the emitted values come later (asynchronously) (JavaScript is single-threaded, but you can treat it similarly to a separate thread). So, there's nothing explicitly wrong with trying to test them with mock data.

`BehaviorSubject` is a bit of a corner case, as it is programmed to emit some type of default value when `subscribe()` is called. Thus, you probably want to skip this value the first time around.

```
  it('should emit filtered products', async(inject([ProductService], (service: MockProductService) => {
    let testId = 'testId';  // you need to define this as appropriate
    let testProduct;        // you need to define this to be something that will be returned when the filter is set

    // subscribe, but skip the first as this is a BehaviorSubject and emits a default first value.
    service.filteredProducts$.skip(1).subscribe((o) => expect(o).toBe(testProduct));

    service.findByUserId(testId);
  })));
```

Writing a spy in this case doesn't seem to make a whole lot of sense, as all you're doing is testing the test code. If you're trying to test the service itself, you can stub the methods that reach back to the server, or you can write  a mock component (which is what I usually do) that does this (and I usually make my mock component and real component share a common base class).

Comment: Why you've put `async`?

Comment: I'm not altogether sure, but I think because things that happen in observables are always asynchronous.

Comment: I was looking for a solution like this. Unfortunately BehaviorSubject doesn't have a skip function (anymore)..

Comment: It looks like since RxJS 6 you have to pipe the skip. `service.behaviorSubject$.pipe(skip(1)).subscribe();`

Comment: Thank you for answering the question. The top voted answer is fine for someone refactoring but doesn't actually answer the question of testing Subjects.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure why you're using a `BehaviorSubject` in the first place, but as your `getProducts()` API is using an observable API anyways, it'd be better to expose it right away so consumers of that API can decide what to do with the emitted value/failure.

By doing that, filtering gets easier as well, plus it'll be easier to test.

#### Change your API

So basically what I'd propose:

```
getProducts(): Observable<Product[]> {
  return this.http.get(...);
}
```

Then in your filter method you can reuse that API

```
filterById(id: string): Observable<Product> {
  return this.getProducts()
             .filter(products => products.find(product => id === product.id));
}
```

And then you'd basically use it as:

```
productService.filterById(id).subscribe(product => ...);
```

#### Test like this

Now in terms of testing you can easily mock the response provided by `getProducts()` and test your filter method:

```
spyOn(productService, 'getProducts').and.returnValue(Observable.of([
  { id: '0', ... },
  { id: '1', ...}
]);

productService.filterById('0').subscribe(product => {
  ...assertions
});
```

#### Cache response

Of course, reaching out to the server every time you filter by id might not be what you want. In such a case it'd be good to teach your service to cache the http response and return it right away if available:

```
getProducts(): Observable<Product[]> {
  if (this.products) {
    return Observable.of(products);
  }
  return this.http.get(...)
    .do(products => this.products = products);
}
```

Something along those lines.

Comment: Thanks @PascalPrecht. I guess it's better to use an `Observable` directly instead of a `BehaviorSubject`? BTW: I am big fan of your work. Thank you for providing so many knowledgeable resources to the community.

Comment: What if I need to use the `BehaviorSubject`? How would I test this?

Comment: @PascalPrect. Your example does not seem to work. I am receiving the following error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined when I try to test this.